# GSON JSON Parsing String versus POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

Curious instance where `gson` parser can parse a JSON string to a `String`, but can't parse that JSON string to the original object it represented.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Reader {
    public class Beta {
        String beta1;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{ beta1: " + this.beta1 + "}";
        }
    }
    public class Alpha {
        Beta beta;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + "beta: " + beta.toString() + "}";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String example1 = "[[{beta:{beta1:beta2}}]]";
        String json = gson.toJson(example1);
        // this throws an error
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Alpha>> dog = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Alpha>>>(){}.getType());
        // this does not
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Alpha>> dog1 = gson.fromJson("[[{beta:{beta1:beta2}}]]", new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Alpha>>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: json keys have to be strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[[{readerme:{dumbme:meme}}]]` is json in the proper format for your `List<List<Alpha>>` object, then serializing the literal string `[[{readerme:{dumbme:meme}}]]`, will not be.

Calling gson.ToJson with a string, will output a string in json format. In effect, your string `[[{readerme:{dumbme:meme}}]]` will become `"[[{readerme:{dumbme:meme}}]]"`. Note the added quotes.
I think printing the contents of the `json` variable to the console will help you understand what I mean by this.

Since this output string is a string represented in json, it is no longer the correct scheme for `List<List<Alpha>>`

Comment: Is the difference a Java String of a JSON string versus a Java String of a JSON object or array?

Comment: Yes, a java string of a json object is a string representation of the object.
A java string of a json string, is a string representation of a string.